# Riemann hypothesis and action principle

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Hello,

I would like to know whether the Riemann hypothesis could be a consequence of some kind of action principle: in other words, can the equation $\zeta(s)=0$ be interpreted as the formulation of some number theoretical action principle?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll vote "Close as not a real question" until the question isn't further clarified.

Comment: So you're asking if there is a functional whose extrema correspond in some reasonable way to the zeros of the zeta function?  If so, this is strikes me as a trivial rephrasing of a well-known pipe dream regarding the zeta function: the Hilbert-Polya conjecture.  But I am also voting to close.

Comment: Well, trivial rephrasing or not, if he came up with it idependently, +1, I'd say. After all, some people are still smoking this pipe after all these years. [Hope this continuation on pipe-dream makes sense.]

Comment: Well, all mathematicians are smoking one pipe or another.

Comment: Read the Article of Ralf Meyer about adeles and L functions, he gives a spectral interpretation. It's on the arxiv, but here is another link: www.math.uni-muenster.de/sfb/about/publ/heft300.ps . He constructs an operator closely related to the right regular action on the adeles. A right regular action on a locally abelian group is always in close connection with the Fourier transform.